# Add tasks for todo list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add tasks for each todo list that has a specific title.

Can I get a specific todo list by its id and add some tasks to it?
I am new to javascript, so I searched google about adding lists for a specific list with no results :(

```
class Model {
  constructor() {}

  this.todos = [
      { 
        id: 1,
       title: 'Outside',
       text: 'Running',
       complete: false,
       tasks: [
       { id: 1, text: 'Run a marathon', complete: false},
       { id: 2, text: 'Run with freinds', complete: false}
       ]
    },
    { 
        id: 2,
       title: 'Garden',
       text: 'Plant',
       complete: false,
       tasks: [
       { id: 1, text: 'Plant a garden', complete: false},
       { id: 2, text: 'Water the garden', complete: false}
       ]
    }];

    addTodo(todoText) {
        const todo = {
        id: this.todos.length > 0 ? this.todos[this.todos.length - 1].id + 1 : 1,
        text: todoText,
        complete: false,
        tasks: []
    }

    this.todos.push(todo)
  }
  }
```

Is it true to do like addTodo function for adding a tasks for a specific todo list like this?

```
addTodoTask(todoTaskText) {
        const todoTask = {
        id: this.todos.tasks.length > 0 ? this.todos[this.todos.tasks.length - 1].id + 1 : 1,
        text: todoText,
        complete: false,
    }

    this.todos.tasks.push(todoTask)
  }
```

and how to add a list of a list in javascript like:

```
<ul>
<li>Running
<ul>
<li>Run a marathon</li>
<li>Run with freind</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems to me you have some confusion between "list", "todo" and "tasks". Not very clear what you want to do. Please reorganize your question.

Comment: what exactly is your expected output ?

Comment: @i.brod I am building a todo app that has lists of todos every list can have multiple tasks, In other words, The user will be able to create multiple lists, give them titles, and add tasks to any of the lists.

Comment: Use `<ul id="outer">` so you can find it with `document.getElementById("outer");` Same for `<li id="outerElem-1">`

Comment: Two tips i can give you: First, consider using a "dictionary", instead of an array. Each element in this object will have a key according to its ID, which will make it much easier to grab the items you need, by ID. Secondly, consider using UUID for a random ID(things might go wrong when you rely on your list length(what happens if you delete an item?)

Comment: @Adder my 2nd problem is with creating a sublist with DOM, I know how to create lists with DOM

Comment: @i.brod two ways I know to delete items, first by clear all from innerHTML and the 2nd way to add a display:none for each item, the pop() is not good for my app because it deletes only the last item added so I can't use it. and thanks for the dictionary, it's an object and I can add another object in it but how to get each object by its id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make each class handle rendering its own content and just map the list items consecutively while rendering from the top-down.

**Edit:** The `render()` methods make use of ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). These are special strings that allow you embed variabes and expressions without the use of string concatenation.

```js
const main = () => {
  let todoList = new TodoList({ todos : getData() })
  document.body.innerHTML = todoList.render()
}

class TodoTask {
  constructor(options) {
    this.id = options.id
    this.text = options.text
    this.complete = options.complete
  }
  render() {
    return `<li>[${this.id}] ${this.text} (${this.complete})</li>`
  }
}

class TodoEntry {
  constructor(options) {
    this.id = options.id
    this.title = options.title
    this.text = options.text
    this.complete = options.complete
    this.tasks = []
    if (options.tasks) {
      options.tasks.forEach(task => this.addTask(task))
    }
  }
  addTask(task) {
    this.tasks.push(new TodoTask(Object.assign({
      id : (this.tasks.length || 0) + 1
    }, task)))
  }
  render() {
    return `<li>
      [${this.id}] ${this.title} (${this.complete})
      <ul>${this.tasks.map(task => task.render()).join('')}</ul>
    </li>`
  }
}

class TodoList {
  constructor(options) {
    this.todos = []
    if (options.todos) {
      options.todos.forEach(todo => this.addTodo(todo))
    }
  }
  addTodo(todo) {
    this.todos.push(new TodoEntry(Object.assign({
      id : (this.todos.length || 0) + 1
    }, todo)))
  }
  render() {
    return `<ul>${this.todos.map(todo => todo.render()).join('')}</ul>`
  }
}

function getData() {
  return [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Outside',
    text: 'Running',
    complete: false,
    tasks: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'Run a marathon',
      complete: false
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Run with freinds',
      complete: false
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Garden',
    text: 'Plant',
    complete: false,
    tasks: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'Plant a garden',
      complete: false
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Water the garden',
      complete: false
    }]
  }]
}

main() // entry
```

Comment: Mr. Polywhirl, please can you edit the render and make it in DOM, and why you are adding a $ sign before {this.id}...

Comment: @Ktb214 Updated my response.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Polywhirl

Answer (score 1):

To add a task your todo, you should have a way of knowing which todo list you're updating. Like using the todo's id.

For example your addTaskToTodo will looks like so.

```
addTask(todoId, taskObject) {
  // find that todos index
  const todoIndex = this.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id ===todoId);
  // using that index update the tasks
  this.todos[todoIndex].tasks.push(taskObject)
}
```

This assumes your taskObject already has all the properties. If you need to manually update its id, you can also do that before pushing by checking the length of the tasks and incrementing by 1.

Answer (score 1):

I made an example of how to use dictionaries instead of arrays, and also a random ID. I think you will find it much cleaner and simpler:

```
class Model {
  constructor() { }

  todos = {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Outside',
      text: 'Running',
      complete: false,
      tasks: {
        1: { id: 1, text: 'Run a marathon', complete: false },
        2: { id: 2, text: 'Run with freinds', complete: false }
      }
    },
    2: {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Garden',
      text: 'Plant',
      complete: false,
      tasks: {
        1: { id: 1, text: 'Plant a garden', complete: false },
        2: { id: 2, text: 'Water the garden', complete: false }
      }


    }
  }


  getRandomId = () => {
    return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  }

  addTodo(todoText) {
    const id = this.getRandomId();
    const todo = {
      id,
      text: todoText,
      complete: false,
      tasks:{}
    }

    this.todos[id] = todo;
  }

  addTodoTask(todoTaskText,todoId) {//Pass also the id of the todo, to know where this task belongs to.
    const id = this.getRandomId();
    const todoTask = {
      id,
      text: todoTaskText,
      complete: false,
    }

    this.todos[todoId].tasks[id] = todoTask
  }
}
```

This way you could easily edit/remove both todos and tasks, just by their id, without using any messy Array.filter and such